# no-referrer-when-downgrade Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

En esta oportunidad vengo por su ayuda por otro tema.

Estoy realizando un formulario en Laravel 5.5, para ingresar en una tabla una lista de servidores, Esta tabla tiene muchas llaves foraneas.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
<?php $title = isset($item) ? $item->name: "Agregar nuevo Servidor" ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

{!! Form::myInput('text', 'hostname', 'Hostname', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'ip', 'IP', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'cpu', 'CPU', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'cores', 'Cores', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'ram', 'Ram (MB)', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'disco', 'Disco (GB)', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::mySelect('id_rol', 'Rol', App\Roles::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
      <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">
          <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="so" id="so" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Seleccionar sistema</option>
                  @foreach($sistemas as $sistema)
                  <option value="{{ $sistema->id }}">{{ $sistema->nombre }}</option>
                  @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
          <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Version Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="version" id="version" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Selecciona un sistema operativo primero</option>
            </select>
          <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <script>

        var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.so') }}"; 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        selectChange(); 
        }); 

        function selectChange(){ 
        $('#so').on('change', function(e){ 
        var idSo = $(this).val(); 
        ajaxSelect(idSo); 
        }); 
        } 

        function ajaxSelect(id)
        { 
            $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            headers: { 
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
            },   
            url: rutaConsulta, 
            data: {id: id}, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            beforeSend: function(){ 
            } 
            }).done(function(response) { 
            var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
            $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem){ 
            html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.version +'</option>' 
            }); 
            $('#version').html(html); 
            }).fail(function(data) { 

            }); 
            }


    </script>

{!! Form::mySelect('id_tipo', 'Tipo', App\Tipos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['required','class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 'Uso', App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['required','id' => 'listaUsos', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

<div class="requerido-con-virtual">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
        <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">

{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
               'Servidor padre:', 
                App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("ip AS ip"), "id")->where('id_uso', '=', 1)-> pluck('ip', 'id')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<!-- MARCA Y MODELO -->

<div class="requerido-con-fisico">

        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
        <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
      <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">


<label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Marca</label>
<br>
<select name="marca" id="marca" style="width: 100%">
   <option value="">Seleccionar marca</option>
      @foreach($marcas as $marca)
      <option value="{{ $marca->id }}">{{ $marca->nombre }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label class="col-sm-5" for="modelo">Modelo</label>
<select name="modelo" id="modelo" style="width: 100%"> 
<option value="">Selecciona un modelo primero</option> 
</select>

<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script> 
  var rutaConsulta2 = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.mod') }}"; 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  selectChange2(); 
  }); 

  function selectChange2(){ 
    $('#marca').on('change', function(e){ 
    var idMarca = $(this).val(); 
    ajaxSelect1(idMarca); 
    }); 
    } 

  function ajaxSelect1(id){ 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    headers: { 
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
    } ,
    url:  rutaConsulta2, 
    data: {id: id}, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    beforeSend: function(){ 
    } 
    }).done(function(response) { 
    var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
    $.each(response.modelos, function(i, elem){ 
    html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.modelo +'</option>' 
    }); 
    $('#modelo').html(html); 
    }).fail(function(data) { 

    }); 
    }
</script>

{!! Form::myInput('text', 'mac', 'Mac', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'serial', 'Serial', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'ubicacion', 'Ubicación', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'propietario', 'Propietario', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

{!! Form::mySelect('id_estado', 'Estado', App\Estados::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

{!! Form::myInput('text', 'observacion', 'Observacion', ['required']) !!}
```

Este es mi modelo

```
class Servidores extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['hostname','ip','cpu','cores','ram','disco','id_padre','id_rol','id_so','id_version','id_tipo','id_uso','id_marca','id_modelo','mac','serial','ubicacion','propietario','id_estado','observacion'];

    /*
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Relations
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    public function parentServidores()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servidores::class);
    }

    public function servidores2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Servidores','id_padre');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Roles','id_rol');
    }

    public function usos()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Usos','id_uso');
    }

    public function so()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\SistemasOperativos','id_so');
    }

    public function versionn()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\SoVersiones','id_version');
    }

    public function tipos()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipos','id_tipo');
    }

    public function estados()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Estados','id_estado');
    }

    public function marcas()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Marcas','id_marca');
    }

    public function modelos()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Modelos','id_modelo');
    }



}
```

Este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Servidores;
use App\Roles;
use App\SistemasOperativos;
use App\SoVersiones;
use App\Tipos;
use App\Marcas;
use App\Modelos;
use App\Estados;


class ServidoresController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $items = Servidores::with('parentServidores','servidores2','roles','so','versionn','marcas','modelos','tipos','estados','usos')->get();

        return view('admin.servidoresVistas.index', compact('items'));
    }



    public function consultarVersiones(Request $request)
    {
       $id_so = $request->id;
       $versiones = SoVersiones::where('id_so', $id_so)->get();


       $respuesta = array();
       $respuesta['versiones'] = $versiones->toArray();   
       return response()->json($respuesta);
    }


    public function consultarModelos(Request $request) 
    { 
        $id_marca = $request->id; 
        $modelos = Modelos::where('id_marca', $id_marca)->get(); 


        $respuesta = array(); 
        $respuesta['modelos'] = $modelos->toArray(); 
        return response()->json($respuesta); 
    }



     /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
       $sistemas = SistemasOperativos::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
       $marcas = Marcas::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();  


    return view ('admin.servidoresVistas.create', compact('sistemas','marcas'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Servidores::create($request->all());

        //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));
        return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.servidoresRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $item = Servidores::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.servidoresVistas.edit', compact('item'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $item = Servidores::findOrFail($id);
        $item->update($request->all());
        //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
        return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.servidoresRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Servidores::destroy($id);

        return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_destroy'));
    }


}
```

Y Estas son mis rutas:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
/*
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Admin
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
Route::group(['prefix' => ADMIN, 'as' => ADMIN . '.', 'middleware'=>['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/', ['uses'=>'DashboardController@index', 'as'=>'dash']);
    Route::get('selectso','ServidoresController@getso');
    Route::post('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones')->name('ruta.consulta.so');
    Route::post('selectmodeloRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarModelos')->name('ruta.consulta.mod');
    Route::get('selectmodeloRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarModelos')->name('ruta.consulta.mod');
    Route::get('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones')->name('ruta.consulta.so');
    Route::resource('rolesRoute', 'RolesController');
    Route::resource('sisopRoute', 'SisopController');      
    Route::resource('tipoRoute', 'TipoController');
    Route::resource('estadosRoute', 'EstadosController');
    Route::resource('usosRoute', 'UsosController');
    Route::resource('serviciosRoute', 'ServiciosController');
    Route::resource('servidoresRoute', 'ServidoresController');
    Route::resource('instanciasRoute', 'InstanciasController');
    Route::resource('ixsRoute', 'IxsController');
    Route::resource('clientesRoute', 'ClientesController');
    Route::resource('ixclientesRoute', 'IxclientesController');
    Route::resource('soversionesRoute', 'SoversionesController');
    Route::resource('marcasRoute', 'MarcasController');
    Route::resource('modelosRoute', 'ModelosController');
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController')->middleware('Role:Superadmin|Admin');
    Route::get('profileedit/{id}', 'ProfileController@edit');
    Route::put('profileupdate/{id}', 'ProfileController@update');


});
```

Habiendo explicado mi codigo, Explico como ocurre mi error:

Tengo una tabla que se llama servidor, y este es el formulario que utilizo para realizar esos ingresos:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Cuando realizo ese ingreso pasa este error:

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

He leido algo sobre este problema en internet y es un tema de rutas, pero el problema que identifique inicialmente, es que cuando realizo ese ingreso, No me toma los datos que selecciono del sistema operativo, la version ni el modelo ni la marca del servidor, apesar de haberlos tomado.

Lamento si es algo extenso el tema, Agradeceria demasiado si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

Quedo atento.

Analizando un poco mas el problema, Encuentro que tengo dos lios puntuales:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
      <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">
          <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="so" id="so" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Seleccionar sistema</option>
                  @foreach($sistemas as $sistema)
                  <option value="{{ $sistema->id }}">{{ $sistema->nombre }}</option>
                  @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
          <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Version Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="version" id="version" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Selecciona un sistema operativo primero</option>
            </select>
          <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
```

Estos campos no me escriben nada en mi tabla servidores, Y, cuando trato de editar un campo desde la pagina, no me deja, por lo que debe ser que al momento de realizar el get, no me trae nada.

Como podria arreglarlo para que tomara esos datos...

Gracias por leer

Actualización 3.0:

Ya logre que guardara en los campos de mi tabla, el problema ahora, sigue siendo con las rutas, Cuando le doy guardar, se muere, a pesar de haberles cambiado el nombre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer es problema de tus rutas:

```
Route::post('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones')->name('ruta.consulta.so');
Route::get('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersiones')->name('ruta.consulta.so');
```

Donde: si bien una es `get` y la otra `post`, hasta ahí todo bien.

El `name`(ruta.consulta.so) debe de ser diferente, pero si aun estando iguales "funcionara" tienes un problema aun mayor dirigiendo ambas **rutas a la misma función dentro del mismo controlador", Error fatal !!!.

Lo mismo pasa en:

```
Route::post('selectmodeloRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarModelos')->name('ruta.consulta.mod');
Route::get('selectmodeloRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarModelos')->name('ruta.consulta.mod');
```

Entonces la solución esta en cambiar de `name` a tus rutas, y de igual manera las funciones a las cuales los diriges, algo asi:

```
Route::post('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersionespost')->name('ruta.consulta.so.post');
Route::get('selectversionRoute', 'ServidoresController@consultarVersionesget')->name('ruta.consulta.so.get');
```

Comment: Hola bro, Muchas gracias por tu colaboración, mira que a pesar de haber realizado el cambio, no se soluciono el problema, peor ya detecte el problema, solo que no se como solucionarlo jajaja, Mira:

El problema es que no me esta guardando los datos servidor, version de servidor marca y modelo. Y el otro problema, es que cuando quiero editar los datos, tambien me devuelve el error, esto debe ser porque obviamente, no sabe de donde traer esos datos, entonces ahí creo que estan los problemas, solo que no se como solucionarlos :V 

Gracias por leer :)

Comment: @OmarNoa, dices que no sabes como editar los datos?, si es el caso habre otra pregunta, esta no esta referida a ello.

Comment: No no, osea, si se como editar los datos, el problema, es que cuando le doy a mi boton editar, Se muere otra vez, he imagino que sera que cuando se realiza el get, para traer los datos de determinado servidor, se muere mi app :( Ese es el problema. Ya encontre como grabar los datos en mi tabla servidor, pero sigue muriendose.